# Using JSONmodel to try and fetch data from a server to ios device

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I've been trying to use JSONmodel to try and get data from my server to my ios device. I've set up my classes properly but for some reason it keeps coming back null after calling the url.

```
feed = [[Feeds alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://http://www.cs4768project.net76.net/untitled.php?action=getShops"
                                         completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {
                                             NSLog(@"reached");
                                             //json fetched
                                             NSLog(@"shops: %@", feed.shops);
```

Here is the model that holds the feeds

```
@interface Feeds : JSONModel
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray* shops;
@end
```

along with my coffee shop class

```
@interface CoffeeShop : JSONModel
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationDegrees latitude;
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationDegrees longtitude;
@end
```

the json output:

```
{"name":"Starbs","latitude":"45","longtitude":"-52"}
```

i've been trying to find a solution for a while and have come up with nothing and im stumped on why this isnt working. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Could it be because there are 2 `http://` in the URL?

Comment: Please show one part of JSON file, and JSON decode code.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam just noticed that and removed it and it still doesnt work. it gives this error when i check the error message error The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: After looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9384914/1702077 it looks like the problem might be the JSON itself, not the parser

Comment: it looks like mine should be fine tho?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well it looks like the JSON has some thing wrong with it because I tried this code

```
NSError *e;
NSDictionary *s = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cs4768project.net76.net/untitled.php?action=getShops"]] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&e];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
if (e) {
    NSLog(@"%@", e);
}
```

and it returns

```
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x1e0529f0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
```

So, if it's your website, I'd change the JSON to a valid format, or contact the owner of the website and notify them of the problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363777/1702077) answer is tells you what the problem is specifically.

Comment: I always use this web site: http://jsonlint.com - it's super fast to validate a json string, no ads, etc. (to the SO overlords: I am not affiliated with them, it's just very useful to quickly check stuff)